# Numeration layout

Tags: sectioning, lists, indentation, numeration

How can I create a numeration with the following Layout:

1. \TAB \TAB Description

\TAB a) \TAB Description

\TAB b) \TAB Description

(see screenshot)

Basically, I want to create a list and sublist layout, where the list (1.,2. etc.) has no left indent, but the sublist (a,b,c etc.) does.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The "outer" question is set as a blank `\item[]` within an "inner" list. The following achieves that, with a newly-defined `question` environment and `\subquestion` macro (for context):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{question}{ +m }{%
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries \arabic*.},ref=\arabic*]
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)},ref=\alph*]
      \item[] {\bfseries #1}
}{
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\subquestion}{}{\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  {\lipsum[1][1-3]}% Main question
  \subquestion \lipsum[1][4-5]% sub-question
  \subquestion \lipsum[1][6-7]% sub-question
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-2]
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \lipsum[2][3]
            \item \lipsum[1][2-5]
        \end{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[4]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. To meet the OP's "no left indent" requirement, you could load the `enumitem` package and change the "outer" `\begin{enumerate}` statement to `\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt]`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstood OP's request, but for me it looks like they want to have the alignment of the text of the inner and outer enumeration.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % only for testing reasons
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength\oldlabelsep \setlength\oldlabelsep\labelsep % store old value
\newlength\mylength    \setlength\mylength{0.7cm} % choose any length that suits you
\setlist{
   itemindent=0cm,
   leftmargin=\dimexpr\leftmargin+\mylength\relax,
   labelsep=\dimexpr\labelsep+\mylength\relax,
}
\setlist[2]{ % adaptions only for level two
   itemindent=\dimexpr\labelwidth\relax,
   leftmargin=0cm,
   labelsep=\oldlabelsep,
   label=\alph*)
}

\def\longtext{This is a very very very very very very very very very long text for testing reasons.} % only for testing reasons

\begin{document}
   \lipsum[2]
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item \longtext
      \begin{enumerate}
         \item\longtext
         \item\longtext
      \end{enumerate}
      \item \longtext
   \end{enumerate}
   \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]